# Is it possible to trigger a script when drive is ejected from the Finder?

Tags: script, eject

I'd like to run a script (removing non-OSX .* files) on a USB drive whenever that drive is ejected - is there a way to trigger a script automatically when a drive is ejected from the Finder?

To clarify: I'm looking for a way of triggering a given script before the `umount` command runs, i.e. immediately before the drive is ejected. I'm aiming to delete .* files and run `dot_clean` before a FAT drive ejects, getting rid of OSX-only invisible files that confuse Windows systems.

Comment: How would you run a script on a USB drive after you have ejected it?

Comment: It would run BEFORE the drive ejects ... when the Finder starts the process of unmounting it. Presumably there is a way of running a script before `umount` runs.

Comment: I don't believe there is anything that allows you to do that. Also, you would perhaps like to edit your question to include that the script should be run run before the drive ejects.

Comment: There is a [hack](http://hints.macworld.com/article.php?story=20110204124029798) to let you do something like this - renaming umount and creating a new umount script that removes dotfiles and then calling the old umount. Will give this a try anyway.

Comment: That’s great! Add that as an answer and accept it so that future visitors with the same problem know that there is a solution.

Answer (score 1):

There is some 3rd party software ([UnDock](http://flyingpapersoftware.com/)) which allows you to run scripts when drives are ejected.

Comment: It doesn't seem to support that. You can only tell it to run scripts when disks are ejected manually with it.